# The meaning of the word "ever" in a certain context

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does the word "ever" mean in this context?

> If you were to head out into the cosmos, traveling **ever** farther, would you find that space goes on indefinitely, or that it abruptly ends?

Does it mean something like "always"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, you've got it right. "Traveling ever farther" could be rephrased as *always traveling farther* or *continually traveling farther* or any number of similar phrases.

*Traveling ever farther* is much more poetic though, which is likely why it was written that way.